# How to create a distorted reflection glass?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders

How to distort a glass reflection to make it look the same as pictured below?
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know about the physics of such glass, But it can be created using standard bump mapping.

[image]

The light path is not necessary here, but just to be cautious ...

Comment: For the right reference image, you can increase the distortion in the noise texture.