# How to make an "old glass" material in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders

I'm asking about the glass found in old windows. It is not just [dirty](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/33054/2217), [scratched](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/32166/2217), or with [varied roughness](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/51814/2217), but it has irregular imperfections in the glass that make all sorts of distortions. Both when looking through the glass (like in the image below), but also and to a greater extent when looking at the reflections.

[image: example of old glass with imperfections]
<sup>Image by TTaylor on [wikimedia commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Window_Glass_03.jpg)</sup>

[image: example of old glass with imperfections]
<sup>Image by Stanzilla on [wikimedia commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Vitres_anciennes.jpg)</sup>

Take a look at the pictures on [this site](https://www.agwglass.com/gallery) or [this page](https://www.restorationglass.com/product-catalog.cfm) to get more of an idea what I'm talking about in the glass.

So how do I make this type of glass in a cycles material?

Comment: Have you tried using a refraction shader mixed with a glass shader using a texture.

Comment: [How about a noise texture + normal mapping?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/66081/599)

Comment: A bit related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66079/how-to-create-a-distorted-reflection-glass

Answer (score 8):

for this kind of things you will want to use either a normal map (using the normal map node under Add node>vector>normal map) or a bump map (using the bump node found under Add node>vector>bump) and feed the normal output into the normal input of your refraction or glass shader

Here is an example setup:

[image]

And the results this gives:

[image]

If you make a proper texture to acomodate for the distortion you are looking for then you should be able to get identical results to the images you provided.

If you decide to use normal maps then you will need to use this fix: www.youtube.com/watch?v=jlOtXtQSxd0

Comment: If you want the same distortion to show up on your reflections you have to feed the normal output from the bump or norrmal map node into the normal input of your glossy shader too

Comment: That looks a little more like heat distortion than reflection distortion.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms An image texture can be used, instead of noise, to get the desired effect.

Comment: Looking cool! The final effect reminds me the photoshop's *aquarelle* artistic filter :).

Comment: This looks like an Impressionistic oil painting.