# Is there a way to have a transparent distorted material in Blender Render?

Tags: rendering, materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm trying to render a transparent glass cube that distorts the objects behind it (with the Blender Renderer). The glass object is basically a very thin cube. I have tried to apply the Raytrace effect to the material like this:
[image]
But when I render, I obtain this result:
[image]
I would like that the red cube behind this glass and the floor are a bit distorted. I tried to modify the index of refraction but didn't work. Is there a way to achieve what I am looking for in Blender Render?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69989/how-to-make-an-old-glass-material-in-cycles

Comment: @cegaton I think it's not as this one is for Blender Internal. Rexam, did you enable Raytrace in Shading scroll in the Render tab?

Comment: Yes, I did. If it was disabled, I didn't get a transparent effect at all.

Comment: The fact that you don't get that distortion is probably caused by the perfectness of the thin cube you use to distort.. As it doesn't have any skewed edges in the corners which happens always in reality light doesn't have any other way to exit from that object other than to bounce only once and that's all. And there won't be any refraction in that case. Try adding Bevel+Subsurf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the kind of distortion you wish to obtain?

[image]

I used a curved subdivided smooth glass and played with some raytrace transparency settings...

Comment: Exactly, but that's the point: you can obtain that effect for a curved surface. Is there a way to do the same for the cube I showed you in my answer (or for a surface that is only slightly curved)?